# Javascript disabling a keyevent and enabling it back

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm quite curious for keyup and keydown function.

I wanted to disable the keys for like 2 seconds then enabling back them.
I've set a function `setTimeout` to ensure to enable it back under this function `continueExecution`.

The issue is , i'm trying to figure out how to disable it.
I've tried 
 `e.preventDefault();`

Tried sending false back still no luck.

Is there something I'm missing?

Event handler:

```
var keysDown = {},
ignore = false,tId;

addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (ignore) return false;
  keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);

addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  if (ignore) return false;
  delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
}, false);
```

Function:

```
function doStuff() {
  hero.y = 0;   
  ignore=true;
  tId = setTimeout(function() { ignore=false; continueExecution() }, 2000) //wait two seconds before continuing

}



function continueExecution()
{   

    hero.y = -281;
}
```

Comment: @J.Titus, mine is for holding down .

Comment: keysDown isn't your listener function, so removeEventListener won't work like that.

Comment: Are you trying to debounce the arrow keys? Then this is an X/Y problem

Comment: @mplungjan, i've updated my question with the full source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your eventListener functions must not be anonymous:

```
function keyDown(e) {
    keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
}
addEventListener("keydown",keyDown,false);

function keyUp (e) {
    delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
}
addEventListener("keyup",keyUp,false);
```

Now you can remove the Listeners:

```
removeEventListener("keyup",keyUp,false);
```

Alltogether:

```
function keyDown(e) {
    keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
}
function keyUp (e) {
    delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
}

function setEvents(){
 addEventListener("keyup",keyUp,false);
 addEventListener("keydown",keyDown,false);
}
setEvents()
function yieldEvents(time){
  removeEventListener("keyup",keyUp,false);
  removeEventListener("keydown",keyDown,false);
  setTimeout(setEvents,time);
}
yieldEvents(2000);//e.g.
```

Comment: This looks very interesting, a sec let me go through it to understand it. 
So when i want to continue, i just set back the event?

Comment: @freedomPride yep. However that will only disable your own click handler, others will still work...

Comment: no luck, there's still some issue enabling it back. should i update my full source on how i tested yours?

Comment: I know that's why i'm blur. Basically when the claw goes down, it should disable others key until reset been initialize

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a flag

```js
// Handle keyboard controls
var keysDown = {},
  ignore = false,tId;

addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (ignore) return false;
  keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);

addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  if (ignore) return false;
  delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
}, false);


function doStuff() {
  ignore = true;
  tId = setTimeout(function() { ignore=false; continueExecution() }, 2000) //wait two seconds before continuing

}
```

Comment: This helps me a lot, but upon i do `continueExecution` , my Y axis doesn't get updated and when i press left, it keeps going to the left and it's not stopping

Answer (score 0):

if you use jquery you can write the code like this :

```
$("your_elem").on("keyup",function(){
     $(this).off("keyup")
});
```

else if you want to return it back you can replace the **off** by the **on** .